# Cropping Image on clientside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am using jQuery *ImgAreaSelect 0.9.10* plugin to crop image uploaded by user.

I am taking input in "multipart/form-data". When I crop image using plugin it gives me coordinates in pixels, but I am looking for coordinates in percentage(%), because I fixed my image in div (size varies from original image size).

Is this possible to get coordinates in % or any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: cropping is done on server side so percentage values will not help you, you would need to convert them back to pixels before cropping.

Comment: If you have the size in pixels that was used to display the image, and the coordinates in pixels as well – then you can easily _calculate_ the percentages yourself. But I doubt that you really need percentages – I suppose you’ll want to apply the crop server-side to the original image dimensions, so you just have to scale the given pixel values … and that should not present a problem to anyone who ever had Math in school … http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication

Comment: @slash197 i think he need % coordinates to render them to user, so user have additional feedback on his cropping. It's not about actual cropping operation, but about its interface.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'imageHeight' and 'imageWidth' to find a % ratio.

```
var xRatio1 = 100*x1/imageWidth,
    yRatio1 = 100*y1/imageHeight,
    xRatio2 = 100*x2/imageWidth,
    yRatio2 = 100*y2/imageHeight
```

From [docs](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html):

```
imageHeight  True height of the image (if scaled with the CSS width and height properties)
imageWidth   True width of the image (if scaled with the CSS width and height properties)
```